# Implementing a search bar in objective-c to search an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, search

I'm trying to add a Search Bar and Search Display controller to my app. I've looked up tutorials for doing this, but all of them assume that the data I want to search is the view's UITableView's data. In my app, the data I want to search through is just an array that I store as a property. The view that the search bar is in has nothing to do with the data I want to search through. Is there any way I can set up my search bar to search a specific array and to not be 'connected' to the view's TableView?

What I want is for the search bar to search through a stored array, and then simply display the search results with an image (check or an x) next to the text, no clicking/selecting would be involved.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a `UISearchController` with your search bar? If so, you can set its updater to any object that implements `UISearchResultsUpdating`, and that object get its data from the array.

Comment: It's showing I have a UISearchBar and a UISearchDisplayController. I don't see any UISearchController. Is that the same as UISearchDisplayController? If so, how do I change it's data source to be my array?

Comment: Following up, I tried to simply set the UISearchDisplayController's dataSource to my array in code, and got this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000263f40'

Comment: And what have you tried yourself? These tutorials you mentioned look like a good starting point - a table view usually has an array as its backing data source. It seems that with a carefull read, you should be able to separate the searching part from the presentation part and use it.